# Align grid starting and ending points when starting grid-item is empty and grid-gap is there

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a column grid where each grid-item has some dynamic width or it can have 0 width also, but because of using grid-gap, even if the width is 0, it's creating a gap.

[image]

So, if you see in the third row, we have empty space before the green column, same in the second row after the blue column, how to avoid this?

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-pond-enyy4?file=/src/styles.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just based on the way you have your markup and styling a quick fix would be to add a `.child` declaration and set `margin: 0 3px;` (or whatever size makes sense) and then set `grid-gap: 0;` in `.item`.  See snippet below.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  height: 20px;
  grid-gap: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-template-columns: 50% 0px 50% 0;
}

.item2 {
  grid-template-columns: 0px 50% 0 50%;
}

.item3 {
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.child3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.child4 {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="item item3">
          <div class="child child1"></div>
          <div class="child child2"></div>
          <div class="child child3"></div>
          <div class="child child4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item1">
          <div class="child child1"></div>
          <div class="child child2"></div>
          <div class="child child3"></div>
          <div class="child child4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item2">
          <div class="child child1"></div>
          <div class="child child2"></div>
          <div class="child child3"></div>
          <div class="child child4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item3">
          <div class="child child1"></div>
          <div class="child child2"></div>
          <div class="child child3"></div>
          <div class="child child4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: working great, thanks.

Comment: thumbs up emoji ;)